# How can I assign hotkey on nautilus option "open file in text editor"?

Tags: 12.10, gnome, nautilus

Im used to F4 in Total Commander, and now looking for how to set it in nautilus.

Comment: Do you mean, select a **text** file/s and press a *shortcut* to open it with `gedit` or your default text editor? Or I'm missing something? If so you, have to press enter and done.